# has_many :through and FormBuilder.fields_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I have a class `Bar` that has a user-defined list of config keys and values, defined like this:

```
class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base

   has_many :config_keys, :through => Foo
   has_many :config_values

end
```

So the available config keys come from the `Foo` class and the values for those come from the `Bar` class.

I'm creating a form for this Bar class, and I need to loop over each of the fields in `config_keys` using the `name` property as the label, but the textbox should be for the `value` of the `config_values`

What I'm seeing is that if I do

I thought that `f.fields_for` on a collection would do the looping for me.

Am I approaching this the right way?  Feels like I'm really fighting the framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting this to work, but the key was don't use f.fields_for bar.config_keys...  instead I make sure that a value record exists for each of the keys (on a before_save on my model) and I do the nested form for the values collection instead.

I'm still not sure why that form builder's object was an array, though.

Comment: Any chance you could elaborate on your solution a bit more? I know I'm interested in how you resolved this...

Comment: Honestly don't remember the context of this, sorry.